# Does Azure LogicApp supports WebDav connection?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, serverless-framework, webdav

I have third party WebDav details to upload a file. So I have to use that there is no option to use FTP as they have refused it.

The file is getting generated via LogicApp and I want to use LogicApp to transfer the file to the location using WebDav.
Does LogicApp support WebDav? What are the alternatives?

Comment: You basically need to be able to install and use the API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/webdav/webdav-portal

Answer (score 0):

Use HTTP connector.  HTTP PUT request method should work. specify the full URL including filename and
that should work